# Is there a way to parse time so that it executes code only once in a given timeframe?

Tags: python, datetime, time, time-format, time-frequency

Let's say I'm listening whether a random event has happened. (Specifically I'm doing this via a webhook. After I receive a webhook, I execute code)

I do not want my webhook event to execute code more than once in a given timeframe, e.g. 30 minutes.
However, I **don't** mean it in this way:

```
"Received webhook?" 
"Wait 30 minutes until you can listen to webhooks again."
```

Somehow I'd like to split the 24hrs of the day into *48 **parts** of 30 minutes*, and then the webhook can activate it's event only once in a given *part*. [for clarification: if it was 20mins then there would be 72 parts of 20mins]

**For example:** The code activates at 14:21. The next possible time I want it to activate would be at 14:30. Until 14:30 I don't want the code to activate more than it already did (once). Then again from 14:30 to 15:00, I want it to activate maximum once, and so on.

I don't necessarily need to divide the day like so, I'm just trying to explain what I need.

I hope I explained myself clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you have two functions `enable` and `disable` that let you enable or disable the webhook. Start by adding a signal handler for `SIGALRM` that enables the hook:

```
signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, lambda: enable())
```

When the hook is triggered, you can do the following:

```
disable()
signal.alarm(1800)
```

This will disable your hook, and request that your program receive a `SIGALRM` signal in 30 minutes. When the signal arrives, your handler will call `enable` to enable your web hook.